# Removing spaces in python input

Tags: python, input, whitespace

I've been trying to use .upper and .replace to turn non standard input like "helLo    woRLD" to "HELLOWORLD" to make it easier to handle.

This seems so simple, and it works fine to turn it to uppercase, but it simply won't remove the spaces.

Code:

```
cmd = input("Please input a command: ")
cmd = cmd.upper()
cmd.replace(" ","")
print("%s" % (cmd))
```

With this, if I enter "Hello World" it would print "HELLO WORLD" with the spaces still there, and I have no idea why it's not working.

EDIT: This is embarrassing, I just realized a literally had to do

```
cmd = cmd.replace(" ","")
```

instead of what I had, flagging this because I figured it out

Comment: Strings are immutable in Python.

Comment: Hint: you need to create a _new_ string.

Comment: Instead of flag, you can just accept the answer. :)

Comment: Why use multiple lines when a single one will do? :) `print(input("Please input a command: ").upper().replace(" ",""))`

Comment: Thank you for the 'embarressing' edit, It saved me some time :)

Answer (score 9):

Strings in python are immutable.  Instead of

```
cmd.replace(" ","")
```

say

```
cmd = cmd.replace(" ","")
```

You could also combine the two commands:

```
cmd = cmd.upper().replace(" ", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd = input("Please input a command: ")
ans = cmd.upper().replace(" ","")
print("%s" % (ans))
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works,but is not the best solution.

```
cmd="hello world"
print("%s" % ("".join(cmd.upper().split(" "))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    while True :
        Word = input('enter string?')
        word = Word.strip()
        print(word)
        #this is the best option as far i am concerned to take input and 
        #removing  whitespaces
        #you can use this if you do not want to take any input
        #Word = 'string  of  a  thing  funny  ? '
        #word = Word.strip()
        #print(word)
```